# Server Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to SQL Server programming and I'm stuck with setting server name and database name at the time of setup. I have tried many websites but I'm not able to understand. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013. I haven't created any database at the first time of installation then how can i enter the database name? I'm confused with this.

When I click on test connection it show the error 40: `failed to establish a connection`.

Secondly there is no folder visible for database diagram in Visual Studio 2013. Can you tell me how to make it visible.

Thank You

Comment: For SQL Server, `[master]` and `[tempdb]` are two databases that always exist.

Comment: @RBarryYoung And The Server Name? Is there an option to use localhost?

Comment: Yes, either use `localhost` or just `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS2013, go to menu option:

**View/Server Explorer**

Then you will see Data Connections which will probably be blank.
Right Click the "Data Connections" text and select "Add Connection"

The source should say *Microsoft SQL Server(SqlClient)*

In Visual Studio 2013 you can create a local database.

In the Server name field type

(LocalDb)\v11.0

Use Windows Authentication.

Press "Test Connection".

It will take a second to start the server, and you should be connected.

Comment: @vinstastic thnx it worked... but i'm still not getting the feature of database diagram in visual studio but the same is available in sql management studio? Anything you could suggest to figure it out...??

Answer (score 1):

You mention you're stuck at 'time of setup'. Were you the one who installed SQL Server on the machine? If you're attempting to use Visual Studio 2013 to connect to a SQL Server instance that hasn't been installed yet, you're going to continue to have all kinds of trouble.

Assuming your SQL Server is up and running with the default instance name, you can choose the server `localhost` and the database `master`, as those always exist. At that point, you'd be able to run `CREATE DATABASE` statements, etc, to build up your table design.

If you need help installing SQL Server that's another question with other answers.

Comment: I have already installed sql Management studio. Database Diagram feature is available in management studio but is not there in visual studio? Any way so that i can integrate the both...??